# Create an order column based on count (sql)

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I have a dataset like this :

```
Groupe | Count     
A      | 22    
B      | 12    
A      | 10    
B      | 16
```

I want to obtain this :

```
Groupe | Count | Total | Order    
A      | 22    | 32    | 1    
B      | 12    | 28    | 2
A      | 10    | 32    | 1    
B      | 16    | 28    | 2
```

So I did this for Total column :

```
sum("Count") OVER (PARTITION BY "Group")
```

It's ok but for order :

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY "Total" DESC)
```

But I get :

```
Groupe | Count | Total | Order    
A      | 22    | 32    | 1    
B      | 12    | 28    | 4    
A      | 10    | 32    | 2    
B      | 16    | 28    | 3
```

Do you know how to create the order column based on total column and in case of equality put the same order to obtain this :

```
Groupe | Count | Total | Order    
A      | 22    | 32    | 1    
B      | 12    | 28    | 2    
A      | 10    | 32    | 1   
B      | 16    | 28    | 2
```

Comment: which database system are you using ?

Comment: How should the final output be sorted? Can you explain what is the expectation here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 
    *,
    DENSE_RANK() over(order by Total desc ) as "Order" 
from 
(
    select 
        Groupe, 
        count, 
        sum(count) over(partition by Groupe)   as Total
    from TableName 
) a
```

Comment: that doesn't work see https://dbfiddle.uk/xIZUk8P_

Comment: The expected output is one and the same. The data is ordered differently. @nbk

Comment: the output must be like the user ask for, #

Comment: There is no particular ordering for the expected output. My understanding is that he is using the input and providing the extra columns with the expected columns. @Nabs335 can you confirm if the ordering should be the same as provided in the question for the final data?

Comment: his question is about order-by see tag, so he wants exactly the sorting as seen in the last table, so a solution for the ordering must be provided

Comment: The users question is on creating the data as per the order column not on ordering the data.

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks for your help. The answer of @TejaGoudKandula solves my problem, I get the table I expected

Answer (score 0):

the only good solution is to add a primary key/identity column to your table and use that to sort

```
CREATE TABLE t
    (id int auto_increment Primary Key,Groupe varchar(1), Count int)
;
```

```
INSERT INTO t
    (Groupe, Count)
VALUES
    ('A', 22)
;
```

```
INSERT INTO t
    (Groupe, Count)
VALUES
    ('B', 12);
```

```
INSERT INTO t
    (Groupe, Count)
VALUES

    ('A', 10)
;
```

```
INSERT INTO t
    (Groupe, Count)
VALUES

    ('B', 16)
;
```

```
select 
     Groupe, 
        count, 
  Total,
    DENSE_RANK() over( order by Total desc ) as "Order" 
from 
(
    select 
  id,
        Groupe, 
        Count
  ,      sum(Count) over(partition by Groupe)   as Total
    from t 
) a 
ORDER BY id
```

| Groupe | count | Total | Order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 22 | 32 | 1 |
| B | 12 | 28 | 2 |
| A | 10 | 32 | 1 |
| B | 16 | 28 | 2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Sp73nWPi)